# How can one stat an entire directory using a single command line starting with bash -c?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, wildcards

How can one stat an entire directory using a single command line starting with bash -c?

This returns all files except for those prefixed with .

```
 bash -c "stat /path/todir/**"
```

This returns all files starting with . including . & .. which should be excluded.

```
bash -c "stat /path/todir/.*"
```

This works but not under bash -c and requires two lines

```
shopt -s dotglob
stat /path/todir/**
```

This too

```
stat /path/todir/!(.|..)
```

Comment: `stat /path/**` would be identical to `stat /path/*` if the `extglob` shell option was not set. You don't set this for your `bash -c` shell, so I don't know how `.` and `..` could be stat'ed.

Comment: I meant `globstar` in my previous comment... not `extglob`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extended glob options are visible only to the current shell and *not* to the sub-shells launched. You need to set them inside the sub-shell also for the glob option to be available. Also `**` does a recursive descent only if another extended option `globstar` is set. For your requirement of the current directory alone, you can just use `*`

```
bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob; stat /path/todir/*'
```

Notice the use of single quotes around the entire shell shell command list. It is much more safe in a way you can avoid unnecessary variable expansion (passing a literal string) and use quoted strings with much ease.

If you have control over the part outside the `'..'` you can set the extended shell option in the invocation itself as

```
bash -O dotglob -c 'stat /path/todir/*'
```

That said, if an option to use external utilities like `find` is available, you could just do below which just excludes the `.` (current directory name) and includes all the files in the current directory and passes it `stat` in one shot.

```
find . ! -path . -exec stat {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bash -c -O extglob 'stat /path/todir/!(.|..)'
```

`-O extglob` enables additional pattern matching operators, including `!(pattern-list)` for negation.

```
[-+]O [shopt_option]
         shopt_option is one of the shell options accepted by the shopt builtin  (see  
         SHELL  BUILTIN  COMMANDS  below). If shopt_option  is  present, -O sets the 
         value of that option; +O unsets it.

If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching
operators  are recognized.  In the following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more
patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of  the  following
sub-patterns:

      ?(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
      *(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
      +(pattern-list)
             Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
      @(pattern-list)
             Matches one of the given patterns
      !(pattern-list)
             Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```